# Some clarifications required

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Is the inductive limit of tensor product $L^{\infty}(X,\mu)^{\otimes \infty}$ is isomorphic to $L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$?

Comment: What do you mean by inductive limit?

Answer (score 2):

No. Take $X = \{0,1\}$ with $\mu(0) = \mu(1) = 1/2$, its infinite tensor product is diffuse.